# DTC - How to know the end of transaction

Tags: .net, transactions, com+, distributed-transactions, mstdc

When we use .net method ContextUtil.SetComplete according to MSDN:
"the COM+ context will commit the current transaction, and the object is deactivated on method return". 
The problem with that I don't know how to add code after the end of transaction ?

Please advise